# ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.CertEnroll'

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.Net 4.0 site that I am editiing in VS2010. Every @ Master and @ Page tag has the blue squiggle lines giving the following error:

ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.CertEnroll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I know it is related to trying to load a 32bit dll into a 64bit application but I am not sure how to control it since I am not sure how this Iterop.CertEnroll client is evening being referenced.

I am targetting Any CPU for my builds.

My application still functions but it bothers me to see all of these warnings and I have seen hints that this may be causing issue with my AjaxToolkit server tags not being recognized.

Thank you!
Karl

Answer (score 0):

I discovered [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/11/07/problems-when-compiling-and-running-code-that-uses-certenroll-with-net-4-0-and-x64.aspx) solution for you. Since I cannot reproduce the error, can't exactly say if it would resolve the error for you, but you can still try. Here is the crux of the story from the link:

> If you compile against x86 platform instead of Any CPU platform (which makes the code to run against x64 platform on x64 systems by default), it will work fine.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling against .NET 4 and not .NET 4 Compact Framework.

I had the same issue not long ago with this missing dependency.

Installing [Microsoft Online Services Sign In](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11859) provides the correct assembly, although I'm not sure why this would be required.

edit: I can't seem to find the article that pointed me to the above download.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556670/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-when-referencing-a-64-bit-assembly) they aren't going to fix. You can try suggested workarounds though.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Check your master page(s) if the `ContentPlaceHolder` tags are specified correctly, and your pages to see that the `ContentPlaceHolder` tag ids are correct.

Long answer:

For anyone facing this issue and if the other solutions do not work, here is another thing you could try. I was getting the same error, with all master and page tags highlighted with the error:

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation,
>   Version=1.3.0.0

My packages were all in order and I spent quite a lot of time trying to get it to work. Turns out the error was misdirecting and the actual error was missing `ContentPlaceHolder` tags in my nested master page.